# Lm317 input connected to output?

Tags: power, lm317, linear-regulator

I am figuring out the schematic of an existing e-bike controller. Specifically I am trying to replace an lm317t with a custom made switch regulator that outputs the same voltage. But first I want to understand the current and existing layout. And I am actually failing on this.

With the help of the multimeter I have come up with an schematic which seems to match with what other people has come up as well:

[image]

full board schematic here:
https://github.com/KingQueenWong/bmsbattery_s06s_controller_hardware/blob/master/S06S-Controller.PDF

Now, I am really puzzled. When I switch on the board VOut is 15V (according to my multimeter), as expected (it is a well known design where the output is known to be 15V). But how that can be if VIn is connected to VOut through a resistor?

To prove my logic I have moved that to LTSpice:

[image]

And as expected, the VOut is basically the VIn plus the resistor drop.

I have checked that the schematic matches with reality 100 of times, and it does (except if I am missing more part, which could be, it is a dense board).

How can this be? What could I miss?

I have opened an issue on that github project, hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Have you tried to load your voltage regulator in LTspice?

Comment: think of the 317 as an auto-adjusting resistor, (dividing) dropping the voltage to the programmed output by sensing the load. All resistors have different voltage on one side than the other; your 3k is no different

Comment: Why does your output show 26.92 volts if it's meant to be 15 volts?

Comment: Your multimeter itself measures through a pretty big resistance. The voltage drop depends on the flowing current, thus any resistance in series will measure vin

Comment: Here you can find a very similarly controller http://www.avdweb.nl/solar-bike/electronics/ku63-motor-controller.html But without these additional resistors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistor is a fairly high value, and so it will not affect regulation provided something is drawing a few mA either from Vout or from the 5V supply.

Note the latter has its own parallel resistance of 750R; with (15V - 5V) across it, that suggests 13mA must be drawn from the 5V supply to keep it within regulation.

This 13mA will keep the 15V supply in regulation for input voltages up to (15V + 13mA * 3k) = 15+39 = 54V, a reasonably safe value from a nominal 36V battery.

Add an adjustable load resistance to your simulation and prove this for yourself.

Leaving 2 questions :

1. why?
2. what keeps the 5V supply drawing at least 13mA?

I'm going to guess, that (2) will involve something like a 5.6V zener diode across the 5V rail so that, in the event the 5V consumption falls below 13mA, the 5V supply rises to 5.6V and turns on the zener. If you have that circuitry, you might want to try and find that zener, or measure its current consumption as you adjust the supply voltage (carefully! from a current limited PSU).

(EDIT : from the complete schematic, I'm not seeing that zener. Possibly the designers added up the currents of all the loads on +5V and concluded they would exceed 13mA, but not by enough to drop the supply below the CPU's minimum voltage if the 7805 failed. I'm guessing they just adjust R59,R60 until it works)

Which leaves (1).

This is part of a vehicle. It is intended to remain safe under all predictable circumstances.

Possibly including the failure of one or both voltage regulators, under which circumstance it must retain enough control (e.g. powering the MCU via a 5.6V 13mA supply) to shut down the vehicle instead of accidentally going to full throttle.

I emphasise these are guesses. I don't know enough context. You have some : the board powered by VOUT and the 5V supply. But the full story is probably only known by the design house and the certification laboratories they used.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two reasons for a 3k bypass resistor:

1. To provide a discharge path for the capacitors when the power is switched off.
2. To reduce the power dissipation in the LM317.

With a 36 V supply the maximum current through the 3k resistor for a 15 V load would be \$ I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {36 - 15}{3k} = 7 \ \mathrm {mA} \$.
If the load draws more than 7 mA then the output voltage from the resistor alone will be < 15 V.

With the addition of the LM317 it can now pass the remainder of the current required to bring \$ V_{OUT} \$ back up to 15 V.

Power dissipation in the 3k resistor will be \$ P = VI = 21 \times 7m = 147 \ \mathrm{mW} \$. This seems low relative to the power handling capability of the LM317 so I suspect that reason 2 is not the right one.

Comment: Why did they decide to use a resistor instead of an ordinary diode as we sometime do?

Comment: You are asking me to get inside the head of the designer. I have no idea!

Comment: @G36 The most likely possibility: the resistor was cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

The full circuit is a quite interesting cut-to-the bone implementation, especially the cost-cutting discrete implementation of a 3-phase bootstrapped MOSFET bridge driver (1/3 shown)

[image]

Here about 60 (!) cheap parts are used to perform most of the functions of an expensive integrated bridge driver chip (or 3 half bridge drivers).

*Most* of the functions. I don't see any LV lockout features implemented, it's possible that under some combination of power-down conditions the bridge driver supply should be brought down relatively quickly before the MOSFETs are damaged from being driven partially on. I suspect that's what the 3K is for. As others have said, there is enough loading in the full circuit to keep the +15V supply from rising out of regulation. I think the 1.5K resistors across the 78L05 are probably to reduce the power dissipation in the chip.

Comment: There is another interesting question about this MOS driver circuit. Why did they decide to add such a large capacitor across gate and source terminal?

Comment: @G36, yes, noticed that- they will add to the gate charge and somewhat slow the switching . I would guess they were getting G-S transients that are close to the maximum allowable for the MOSFETs, and that was the cheapest way to tame them.